# How to improve UITableView scrolling performance? What I am I missing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, smooth-scrolling

I know the basics, what not to do in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, that may cause scrolling performance to be hindered. And I believe I have followed those rules, which is why I have gotten this far. My `UITableView` is horrible at scrolling, does so very well, but there are times where it stutters for split seconds to seconds, noticeable when it starts to slow down a bit.

Without revealing too much of my code, what here am I doing that could be causing this. I think I have gone over everything and eliminated something that could be causing it, but the problem persists. I feel as if it is something that is obvious and I am overlooking. Help is tremendously appreciated.

Thank you.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"tweetCell";

    TweetCell *cell = (TweetCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    NSDictionary *tweet = _tweets[indexPath.row];

    NSString *username = tweet[@"username"];

    CGFloat tweetHeight = [tweet[@"contentHeight"] floatValue];

    cell.tweet.frame = ({
        CGRect frame = cell.tweet.frame;
        frame.size.height = tweetHeight + 2;
        frame.origin.y = cell.bounds.size.height / 2 - frame.size.height / 2;
        frame;
    });

    cell.tweet.attributedText = tweet[@"attributedText"];

    cell.imageView.image = [_profilePhotos[username] valueForKey:@"image"];

    cell.date.text = tweet[@"dateString"];

    if (tweet[@"media"]) {

        cell.tweetImage.image = tweet[@"media"];
        cell.tweetImage.hidden = NO;

    } else {

        cell.tweetImage.image = nil;
        cell.tweetImage.hidden = YES;
    }

    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [tweet[@"attributedText"] mutableCopy];

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"useDynamicTextSize"]) {

        UIFont *font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];

        if (cell.tweet.font.pointSize != font.pointSize) {
            cell.tweet.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:font.pointSize];
            cell.username.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:font.pointSize];
            cell.date.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:font.pointSize];

            [attributedText addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:font.pointSize] range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length)];

        } else {
            [attributedText addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:cell.tweet.font.pointSize] range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length)];
        }
    } else {
        [attributedText addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:17] range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length)];
    }

    cell.tweet.attributedText = attributedText;

    cell.username.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

    NSString *color = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"color"];
    if ([color isEqualToString:@"automatic"]) {
        color = ([[UIScreen mainScreen] brightness] <= .5) ? @"black" : @"white";
    }
    [cell.imageView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [cell.imageView.layer setCornerRadius:5];
    [cell.imageView.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:0/255.0 blue:0/255.0 alpha:0.55] CGColor]];
    [cell.imageView.layer setBorderWidth:0.5];

    [cell.tweetImage.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [cell.tweetImage.layer setCornerRadius:5];
    [cell.tweetImage.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:0/255.0 blue:0/255.0 alpha:0.55] CGColor]];
    [cell.tweetImage.layer setBorderWidth:0.65];

    //  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    //  [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
    //  [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

    if ([color isEqualToString: @"white"]) {
        cell.tweet.textColor =[UIColor blackColor];
        cell.date.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.username.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.tweet.linkTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blueColor]};

        [tweet[@"attributedText"] addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                                         value:[UIColor blackColor]
                                         range:NSMakeRange(0, cell.tweet.attributedText.length)];

    } else /*if ([color isEqualToString: @"black"])*/ {
        cell.tweet.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.date.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.username.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:52/255.0 green:52/255.0 blue:52/255.0 alpha:1];
        cell.tweet.linkTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor colorWithRed:0.66 green:0.82 blue:1 alpha:1]};

        [tweet[@"attributedText"] addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                                         value:[UIColor whiteColor]
                                         range:NSMakeRange(0, cell.tweet.attributedText.length)];
    }

    //  [UIView commitAnimations];

    if (_retweets[_tweets[indexPath.row][@"id"]]) {
        if ([color isEqualToString: @"white"]) {
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.945 green:0.945 blue:0.945 alpha:1];

        } else if ([color isEqualToString: @"black"]) {
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.114 green:0.114 blue:0.114 alpha:1];
        }

        //        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, cell.bounds.size.width);

    } else {
        if ([color isEqualToString: @"white"]) {
            [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        } else if ([color isEqualToString: @"black"]) {
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:52/255.0 green:52/255.0 blue:52/255.0 alpha:1];
        }

        //        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 80, 0, 0);
    }

    cell.tweet.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.tweetImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    cell.tweet.frame = ({
        CGRect frame = cell.tweet.frame;
        frame.size.height = tweetHeight + 2;
        frame.origin.y = cell.bounds.size.height / 2 - frame.size.height / 2;
        if (tweet[@"media"]) {
            frame.size.width = 164;
        } else {
            frame.size.width = 224;
        }
        frame;
    });

    cell.tweet.delegate = self;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(retweetTweet:)];
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
    [cell.tweet addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showImage:)];
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [cell.tweetImage addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapToViewProfile = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewProfile:)];
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [cell.imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [cell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapToViewProfile];

    return cell;
}
```

`TweetCell.m`:

```
//
//  TweetCell.m
//  Khabara
//
//  Created by Isa Ranjha on 3/26/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Isa Ranjha. All rights reserved.
//

#import "TweetCell.h"

@implementation TweetCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    //self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(self.imageView.frame.origin.x,self.imageView.frame.origin.y,45,45);
    self.imageView.frame = ({
        CGRect frame = self.imageView.frame;
        frame.size = CGSizeMake(48, 48);
        frame.origin.y = self.bounds.size.height / 2 - frame.size.height / 2;
        frame;
    });

    self.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    //_tweet.numberOfLines = 0;
    _tweet.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    _tweet.canCancelContentTouches = YES;


    //    _tweet.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin);
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

Comment: This is what Instruments is for. Profile the app. Avoid the guessing.

Comment: BTW - you have a serious bug. You keep adding more and more gesture recognizers to the cells as you scroll and the cells get reused.

Comment: One other suggestion - you have a custom cell (`TweetCell`). If you have a custom cell class, why is so much of the cell logic and setup still in the view controller? Put it all in the cell class.

Comment: Whoa, completely missed the UIGestureRecognizer one, thanks for that. And I will look into doing this in the cell's class.

Comment: Also you can move all the common code like setting layer properties, frame inside cell as they remain the same and you need not redo every time. You can also use two type of cells having different font and look with different reuse identifiers. Based on the type you can use one cell type or the other.

Comment: Time Profiler says this line is taking the most time.     TweetCell *cell = (TweetCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

Comment: Something is missing. What if you can't dequeue a cell? i.e. there are no cells. There should be a line `if(!cell)` or `if(cell == nil)` where you create it. I'm not saying this will solve the problem, but you've got to show everything for the sake of completeness.

Comment: I actually tried that and created a NSArray in that statement, code inside there wasn't getting called and it was a mess. But when I finally did get it working, the problem, as you said, was still not solved.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the set layer corner radius on cell. It make the problem. Instead of this, you better create a frame .png image.

Comment: I commented it out, didn't make too much of a difference in scrolling performance?

Comment: What about attributedText. I'm pretty sure that it's the problem of drawing things. Comment out everything and uncomment each line to trace out.

Comment: Commented that out, same. The cells now have no text.

Comment: Time Profiler says this line is taking the most time.     TweetCell *cell = (TweetCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];